# The function $h$ is given by $h(x)=(2+2 \ln(\ln(t))−(\ln(t))^2)dt$ for $1.1≤x≤7$. On what intervals, if any, is $h$ increasing?

Tags: calculus

The function $h$ is given by $$h(x)=\int_{1.1}^x(2+2\ln(\ln(t))−(\ln(t))^2)dt$$ for $1.1≤x≤7$. On what intervals, if any, is $h$ increasing?

I understand that the second fundamental theorem of Calculus is needed to solve this, but I don't understand how to use it for  $2\ln(\ln(t))$, and for $\ln(t)^2$. Should I use the chain rule for the 2nd part of the equation?

Comment: **Hint**: you need to solve $h'(x) = 2+2\ln(\ln x)-(\ln(x))^2 > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, we are interested in the inequality:
\begin{align*}
2 + 2\ln(t) - \ln^{2}(t) \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow 3 - (1 - 2\ln(t) + \ln^{2}(t)) \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 3 - (1 - \ln(t))^{2} \geq 0 \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |1 - \ln(t)| \leq  \sqrt{3}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow -\sqrt{3} \leq 1 - \ln(t) \leq \sqrt{3}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 1 - \sqrt{3} \leq \ln(t) \leq 1 + \sqrt{3}
\end{align*}

Now you have to check out if the inequality above holds when $t\in[1.1,7]$.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @GunnerHodges You are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Comment: You have $\log t$, where the question has $\log\log t$. So either the question was stated incorrectly, or your answer does not apply.

Comment: oh wait that doesn't work. I figured it out though. The answer is from 1.1<x<2.718.

Comment: @GunnerHodges. There is an explicit solution of $h'(x)=0$. Take care that $1.1<x<2.718$ is not correct

Comment: but if the answer is when the derivative of h is positive, which it has a vertical asymptote at around 1.1, and is positive until 2.718. did I forget a step?